# Why does function calls to templatized base classes not work?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following example:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    public:
        void f() {
            cout << "A::f()\n";
        }
};

template<>
class A<int> {
};

template<typename T>
class B: public A<T> {
    public:
        void g() {
            cout << "B::g()\n";
            A<T>::f();
        }
};

int main() {
    B<int> b;     // (1)
    b.g();        // (2)

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously the call to A::f() inside B::g() will fail for int template type. My question is at what point does the call fail? At (1) or (2)? I thought it should be (1) because at that point the compiler creates a new class with the template type int and compiles it. That compilation should fail in f() correct?

Comment: @John: None, because compilation will fail.

Comment: Oh, ok. I was confused because you were talking about "at what point does the call fail," -- and commented points in the code -- as if it had compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails at 2). Member function of templates are instantiated when called.

More precisely: When a class template is instantiated, the declaration of its member functions are instantiated, but not their definition. The definition is instantiated when the function is used.

Comment: An interesting fact is that if you remove function `f` from all template definitions or explicit specializations of `A` in that TU, then the compiler is allowed to mark the definition of the member function `g` ill-formed and issue a diagnostic even if `B` is never used, because no valid specialization could ever be generated for that member function (`14.7/8`).

Answer (score 4):

It will fail at (2), and this is guaranteed by the standard. In section 14.7.1/1, it says instantiating a template class does *not* instantiate it's members definitions. That will only happen once the member is used.

If you remove (2) from the code, it will compile.

> 14.7.1/1 excerpt:
>   The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit
>   instantiation of the declarations, **but not of the definitions or default arguments, of the class member functions, member classes, static data members and member templates**; and it causes the implicit instantiation of the definitions of member anonymous unions.

Emphasis mine.

---

Visual Studio's diagnosis is misleading. It will say `see reference to class template instantiation 'B<T>' being compiled`. What it means is not "I'm failing at the instantiation of `B<T>`", but "I'm failing at instantiating a member of the class `B<T>`"

Comment: The best thing is that VC only points to the line that instantiates `B`. Anyway, i should have learned by now to doubt VC and simply look it up first.